# Database not exist in docker compose on windows debian subsystem

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I want to try to dockerize my Django project, but I face a problem that the database doesn't exist. I run docker on WSL2. I use PostgreSQL.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Try adding `- DATABASE_HOST=db` on line 28

Even though you are running all the containers on your host. They do not share `localhost` nor `127.0.0.1`. Docker creates its own network and every containers have its own IP address(es) and Network interface(s).

When using Docker Compose, you can use the service name in this case `db` and `web` to point to a container. You can also use `host.docker.internal` to point at the actual host.

In your case, Django is trying to connect to a database that runs on the `web` container but there is none.